# Want some window numpad shortcut back experienced in an older version

Tags: keyboard, window, shortcuts, shortcut-keys

I've have trouble retrieving coarsely some older default numpad keybinding for moving current window around.

I may have forgotten to look to a conventionnal place to activate this like a web page or a built in user friendly configuration tool.
In that case, I'd be pleased to learn it from anyone and to refer to it in later cases.

I remember using them in an older ubuntu's LTS and they did something like that:

- *ctrl + Alt + 1 (numpad)* : move focused window to the bottom left quarter of screen
- *ctrl + Alt + 3 (numpad)* : move focused window to the bottom right quarter of screen
- *ctrl + Alt + 7 (numpad)* : move focused window to the top left quarter of screen
- *ctrl + Alt + 9 (numpad)* : move focused window to the top right quarter of screen
- *ctrl + Alt + 2 (numpad)* : move focused window to the top half of screen
- *ctrl + Alt + 8 (numpad)* : move focused window to the bottom half of screen
- *ctrl + Alt + 4 (numpad)* : move focused window to the left half of screen
- *ctrl + Alt + 6 (numpad)* : move focused window to the right half of screen
- hopefully, I got this one: *ctrl + Alt + 5 (numpad)* : maximize focused window

I'm looking for a default and user friendly way to activate / deactivate them if possible.

FYI, on my system:

`uname -srvo`:

> Linux 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 GNU/Linux

`lsb_release -a`:

> No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>   Description:  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Release: 18.04 Codename: bionic

Thank you for your comprehension.

Comment: Shortcuts may be defined / modified under **Settings | Devices | Keyboard**.

Comment: An "older LTS" can only be 16.04 which used Unity DE. The current LTS is 18.04 and is the first LTS release to use Gnome DE. Shortcuts are DE dependent.

Comment: Thank you @FedonKadifeli. Unfortunately, I haven't found yet the foresaid shortcuts here...

Comment: Thank you @GabrielaGarcia. I suppose you have guessed the main cause here. Still, I hope someone would show me some way to have similar shortcuts in gnome DE...

Comment: My version is 19.04. I do not have much information about 18.04. I guess there is no `gnome-control-center` command (*GNOME Settings*) in your version.